# .htaccess blocks all file access, regardless of commands

Tags: .htaccess

my .htaccess file is blocking everything, even when there are no commands in it to do so.

Here is my file contents

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.example.com/.*
RewriteRule .*\.mp3 - [NC,F]
```

This is blocking all files of any type, regardless of where the request comes from. In fact if I delete all lines and just leave

```
RewriteEngine On
```

everything is still blocked.

please help.

cheers

Comment: If your request is still blocked with nothing in the `.htaccess` file, it is probably not its fault. What about access logs, error logs? Try putting gibberish in the `.htaccess` file and see if you get an error or else look elsewhere (like `httpd.conf`) if that is accessible. A little bit more detail will help.

Comment: What do you mean by "blocked". What http response code do you get? 200? 404? 500? 403? 301/2? Please open your developer console and examine the request that is made.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. What i mean by blocked is, that the files are inaccessible. There are no errors in the php or apache logs. I have full control of the server. If I put gibberish in the .htaccess file, there is no effect. I can directly access the files. however if I simply put "RewriteEngine On" in the .htaccess, I can no longer access any of the files in the .htaccess folder, via the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself.
Turns out my .htaccess was not being honoured at all.

The solution was to remove 
+FollowSymLinks from the apache config file, in the directory area

```
<Directory "/var/www">
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Also modrewrite may actually have not been enabled. I did this from the command line with.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and then restarted apache

```
service apache2 restart
```

Hope this helps someone else. cheers